# Update Neo4j Cypher query throws NotSupportException

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have the following Neo4jClient Cypher query:

```
public TModel Update(TModel model)
{
    return GraphClient.Cypher.Match(string.Format("(e:{0})", typeof(TModel).Name))
                      .Where<IEntity>(e => e.Id == model.Id)
                      .Set("e = {model}")
                      .WithParam("model", model)
                      .Return(e => e.As<TModel>())
                      .Results
                      .Single();
}
```

This method gets a model and updates an existing one by using the Id of it.

This method is part of a generic repository which also has a Save(), GetAll(), GetById() in the same manner. However, the update method for the following reason fails:

NotSupportedException is thrown with message:

```
Unhandled node type MemberAccess in MemberExpression: Convert(value(Refugee.DataAccess.Neo4j.Repository.Neo4jRepository`1+<>c__DisplayClass2[Refugee.DataAccess.Graph.Models.Refugee]).model).Id
```

Comment: I can get this to work fine - so I suspect it's something to do with your classes you're serializing: 1. What is the `Refugee` type?
2. I assume you have an `where TModel : IEntity` on your class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very bizarre. I had to store the model.Id in a temporary variable inside the method and then use the temporary variable to the lambda expression in order to make it work.